# how to use multiple buttons in formvalidation without using type="submit"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, formvalidation.io

I have implemented form validation, when i click on the submit button, whole page is getting refreshed.

But my task is to submit the form and stay on that page only.

here is the below code, please suggest me how to Achieve that.

```
enter code here
\\ Formvalidation code
     }
}).on('success.form.fv', function (e) {

    //e.preventDefault();
    //fv = $(e.target).data('formValidation'); // FormValidation instance\

    //fv.disableSubmitButtons(false);

    //InternaryTicketInvoiceSave();

    var $form = $(e.target),
   $button = $form.data('formValidation').getSubmitButton(),
   $statusField = $form.find('[name="status"]');

    switch ($button.attr('id')) {

        case 'btnTicketSave':
            InternaryTicketInvoiceSave();
            break;
        case 'UpdateStatus':
            InternaryTicketInvoiceSave();
            chnageSatatus();
            break;
       }


     });


     }
    //view code
     <form id="Iform" name="Iform" method="post">
        \\view code here
     </form>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax to post your data if you want to stay on the same page

Answer (score 0):

use html 5 validation 
i.e sample example

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="fname" required>
 <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

detail
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: OP is not asking how to validation

Comment: Thanks for the comment. we have implemented form validation every where and now its not possible and few functionality can be achieved by form validation IO plugin only.

Comment: html5 is easy to use and it will not refresh page other wise if you are not willing to use it then ajax is another option

Comment: for ajax follow this example 
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax-validate/

Answer (score 0):

I was missing e.preventDefault();